# How to use DrawTable using dbAutoTrack

Tags: c#, pdf

I am using  dbAutoTrack for generate PDF in that I have to add Table but I get the Exception like object references is not set to an instance of object

Below is my code

```
  Table t=new Table();
  Row row=new Row(t);

  row.Cells.Add("ABC");
  t.Rows.Add(row);
  _pdfGraphics.DrawTable(100,200, t);
```

where _pdfGraphics is object of PDFGraphics.
Thanks in Advances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer didn't work for me and I was still getting null reference exceptions. It turns out that the rows need to be added with a TableStyle otherwise the cells, for whatever reason, won't be generated:

```
StandardFonts standardfont = StandardFonts.Helvetica;
PDFFont fontSmall_reg = new PDFFont(standardfont, FontStyle.Regular);
TableStyle ts = new TableStyle(fontSmall_reg, 12, nullBorder);

Table data = new Table(ts);
data.Columns.Add(100);
data.Columns.Add(100);

Row r = new Row(data, ts);
r.Height = 25;
r.Cells.Add("Row 1 Col1");

data.add(r)
r.Cells.Add("Row 1 Col2");
```

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you have message like: "Not enough columns in this row to have a column span of 1." And you needed just to add them.

Workable sample:

```
        //Initialize a new PDF Document
        Document _document = new Document();   

        _document.Title = "Аpitron Sample";
        _document.Author = "StanlyF";
        _document.Creator = "АPItron LTD.";

        Page page = null;
        PDFGraphics graphics = null;

        Table _table =  new Table();
        _table.Columns.Add(30);
        Row row = new Row(_table);
        row.Height = 25;
        row.Cells.Add("ABC");
        _table.Rows.Add(row);
        while (_table != null)
        {
            //Initialize new page with default PageSize A4
            page = new Page(PageSize.A4);

            //Add page to document
            _document.Pages.Add(page);
            //Get the PDFGraphics object for drawing to the page.
            graphics = page.Graphics;
            _table = graphics.DrawTable(100,200, _table); 

        }

        using(FileStream _fs = new FileStream("Table_Sample.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))  
        {
            //Generate PDF to the stream
            _document.Generate(_fs);
            Process.Start("Table_Sample.pdf");
        }
```